# How to run Spring application by Maven Tomcat7 via HTTPS?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, ssl, https

To enable HTTPS, I have create self-signed ssl certificate using keytool -genkey, then configured the same in pom.xml

In pom.xml, i used the following code:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- application path always starts with / -->
                <path>/</path>
                <!-- http port -->
                <port>8080</port>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>src/main/tomcatconf/xxx.keystore</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>xxx123</keystorePass>
                <warRunDependencies>
                    <warRunDependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>a groupId</groupId>
                            <artifactId>and artifactId</artifactId>
                            <version>version</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </dependency>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </warRunDependency>
                </warRunDependencies>

                <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>

                <extraDependencies>
                    <extraDependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                        <version>10.1.3.1</version>
                    </extraDependency>
                    <extraDependency>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </extraDependency>
                </extraDependencies>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

But it didn't work out, then i used serverXml parameter in pom.xml and added server.xml file in webapps path.

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <Server port="${shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

<Listener
    className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener"
    port="${jmx.port}" bind="127.0.0.1" useSSL="false"
    passwordFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.password" accessFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.access"
    authenticate="true" />

<Listener
    className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer" />

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"
    SSLEngine="on" />

<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
        type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved"
        factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
        pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>


<Service name="Catalina">

    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="tomcat-http--"
        maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="50" />


    <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100"
        connectionTimeout="20000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" keyAlias="tcserver"
        keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/xxx.keystore" keystorePass="xxx123"
        maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="${bio-ssl.https.port}"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" redirectPort="${bio-ssl.https.port}"
        scheme="https" secure="true" />

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
            resourceName="UserDatabase" />

        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="false"
            name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Context docBase="../../webapp" path="/webapp" reloadable="true" />
        </Host>

    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Again the second method also didn't work out, so tried another one, where i tried to use keytool-maven-plugin to generate keystore in pom.xml itself.

For that i added the following code in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>genkey</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>genkey</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-ssl.keystore</keystore>
                <dname>cn=localhost</dname>
                <keypass>tomcat-learn</keypass>
                <storepass>tomcat-learn</storepass>
                <alias>tomcat-learn</alias>
                <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- application path always starts with / -->
                <path>/</path>
                <!-- http port -->
                <port>8080</port>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>${project.build.directory}/tomcat-ssl.keystore</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>tomcat-learn</keystorePass>
                <warRunDependencies>
                    <warRunDependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>a groupId</groupId>
                            <artifactId>and artifactId</artifactId>
                            <version>version</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </dependency>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </warRunDependency>
                </warRunDependencies>

                <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>

                <extraDependencies>
                    <extraDependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                        <version>10.1.3.1</version>
                    </extraDependency>
                    <extraDependency>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </extraDependency>
                </extraDependencies>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Again, the above third option also didn't work out, please help me to resolve any of the three methods I used. Please suggest a way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achive? Run tomcat server in https mode and deploy your spring application using maven plugin? or run a embedded tomcat server in https?

Comment: yes i'm trying to run my spring application via https. Anyway i got the answere. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello [Nayana_Das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181136/nayana-das),

I managed to get it working by doing this:

**pom.xml**

```
    <build>

    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                    <server>localhost</server>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <port>8080</port>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>${project.build.directory}/tomcat7.keystore</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>tomcat7</keystorePass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>clean</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <id>genkey</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${project.build.directory}/tomcat7.keystore</keystore>
                <dname>cn=localhost</dname>
                <keypass>tomcat7</keypass>
                <storepass>tomcat7</storepass>
                <alias>tomca7</alias>
                <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

1. Execute tomcat7:run for the tomcat plugin;
2. open a browse and type https://localhost:8443/yoururl (if any url);
3. it will complain about security issues, just continue;

Answer (score 0):

As HTTPS enabling via maven tomcat plugin didn't worked for me, i went for another method, so, when i try to use jetty server, to deploy my application, it worked. And the credit goes to this [site](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/05/configure-maven-jetty-plugin-for-ssl.html). It gives a very simple way to configure Maven Jetty plugin for SSL communication.

Thanks to [Hinotori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054014/hinotori) for posting the right answer to enable HTTPS using maven tomcat7.